# Spring boot dynamic database URL based on REST parameters

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, dynamic

I am using Spring boot to develop an application, we have one database for each customer, and the main problem is to avoid creating one instance for each, connected to a single database. With that in mind, I got stuck in the following situation:

I need my application to make connections to several different databases, witch Aliases I don't know when the application starts. Those aliases will be provided via REST requests, so it's dynamic.

All other credentials are equal on the databases, the Driver, URL, username and password, I really just need to change the alias to provide the right URL for that request.

I've done it creating datasources at the momment of the request, like this:

```
private static void selectAll(String alias){

    String sql = "select * from user";

    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+alias);
    dataSourceBuilder.username("username");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("password");
    DataSource dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.build();

    try {
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
        con.prepareStatement(sql).executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But by doing things that way, i can't use criteria and hibernate, and I have to map my objects retreived from the database by hand and write my own simple SQLs for each object/table.

**The main question is, can i use Entities and Repositories (Spring data) with dynamic databases, or if I go for this I'll have to choose between those and having one instance for each customer, connected to a single database.**

I've searched on forums, and the solutions are eigther based on static connections, configured inside Application.properties, or they assume that the the URL is known.

Thank you for your help, any other better aproaches are wellcome, any toughts at all.